# Grant different access to documents folder for different groups

Tags: security, permissions, document, public-group

I have a document folder and two user groups that need different access for them:

- one of the groups should be able to create documents in the folder,
- the other group should be able to read documents from that folder but neither edit them or create new documents in it.

So far, I've only been able to grant the same access to anybody that uses the folder (either everybody can only read, or everybody can read/write). Is there a way to achieve different levels of access for different groups?